# Calculate the Taylor Polynomial

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, taylor-series

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5WSD.png)

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V5SL.png)

I need help with the cosh(x)

```
def taylorCosh(x, n):
    y = 0
    for k in range(n):
        y += (x ** (2 * k)) / (math.factorial(2 * k))
        return y

nVariables = [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
xVariables = [(1/32), (1/16), (1/8), (1/4), (1/2), 1, 2, 4]

x_pos=0
for i in xVariables:
    x_pos+=1
    globals()['Exact_x%s'% x_pos]=math.cosh(i)
    for num in nVariables:
        try:
            globals()['Taylor_x%s'% x_pos+'_n%s'% num]= taylorCosh(i,num)
        except:
            print("Exception thrown for n=",num, "and x=", i)
```

I did up to here but for some reason, the last part is not giving me an output, it's running but not giving me an output, Can someone please help me with this. The code where it's starting from x_pos = 0 from there to the end, when I run that section it should give me output with the exception thrown for n values and the x values.

Comment: Did you mean to `return y` at the first step of your for loop or is that a typo? It should be de-indented 1 level.

Comment: No, the issue is with the 2nd and the 3rd For loop in the 3rd Step.